# Shorter way of evaluating the determinant of a $3\times 3$ Matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

[image]

Is there any short way of evaluating this?-I try to do it, but i end up making mistakes somewhere. The answer is supposed to be(I'm sorry I don't know how to resize the image):

[image]

But I never get this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a Laplace expansion of a determinant along any row or column. If there are any zeroes in your matrix, choose the row or column with the most zeroes, so that you have less terms in the expansion.
For example, the last row of your matrix has a 0 in the second column, so I would choose to expand the determinant along that row (or the second column, your choice).
Using the last row, the Laplace expansion of the determinant is:
$$\begin{split}\frac{33}{20}\cos(v)\left|\begin{array}{cc}-\frac{1}{5}r(v+5)\sin(v)\sin(u) & r\cos(u)\left(\frac{\sin(v)}{5}+\left(\frac{1}{5}v + 1\right)\cos(v)\right)\\
\frac{1}{5}r(v+5)\sin(v)\cos(u) & r\sin(u)\left(\frac{\sin(v)}{5}+\left(\frac{1}{5}v + 1\right)\cos(v)\right)\end{array}\right| \\
- \frac{33}{20}r\sin(v)\left|\begin{array}{cc}\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{5}v\bigr)\cos(u)\sin(v) & -\frac{1}{5}r(v+5)\sin(v)\sin(u)\\
\frac{1}{5}(v+5)\sin(v)\sin(u) & \frac{1}{5}r(v+5)\sin(v)\cos(u)\end{array}\right|\end{split}$$
The determinants of the 2x2 matrices are straightforward. Factoring out common factors, we get:
$$\begin{split}\frac{33}{100}r^2(v+5)\sin(v)\left[-\cos(v)(\cos^2(u)+\sin^2(u))\left(\frac{\sin(v)}{5}+\left(\frac{1}{5}v+1\right)\cos(v)\right)\\ - \sin^2(v)\left(1+\frac{1}{5}v\right)\left(\cos^2(u)+\sin^2(u)\right)\right]\end{split}$$
Apply the Pythagorean identity $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$, expand the remaining binomial product in the first term within the square brackets, and pull out the common factor of $\frac{1}{5}$ to get:
$$\frac{33r^2}{500}(v+5)\sin(v)[-\sin(v)\cos(v)-(v+5)(\cos^2(v)+\sin^2(v))]$$
Applying the Pythagorean identity once more, we arrive at your expression, with the opposite sign. I believe your final answer does not have the correct sign, which my computer algebra system confirms.

Comment: Im going to try it out from scratch using the method you have shown and see if I get the same result. But thank you very much

Comment: @AnjaneyM No problem! I spent some time checking it when I realized I got the opposite sign to your answer. One thing about my answer: the first component (row 1, column 1) of the first matrix in the expansion has a - sign in front, but for some reason the sign will not render in LaTeX. You can see it in your original matrix.

Comment: @RonaldLett Fixed the minus sign. The problem was that the *array* environment must have formatting options that were missing.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: expand the determinant along the last row. You get the sum of two $2\times 2$ determinants with many common factors in the columns. You may perhaps factor out the factor $\frac15 r(v+5)\sin v$ from the second column first to make it even easier.

Comment: I didn't think of that, I will try it out. Thank you

Comment: @AnjaneyM This is pretty much what I suggested in [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1492822/170231).

Comment: yeah from your steps, understood the whole concept perfectly.  And while doing research on the Jacobian theory for changing variable, it became more clear. But the matrices was hard for me because it was quite long even though one of them canceled cause of the 0. Im sorry

Comment: The first one has become much nicer, but the second one is still really long

Comment: @AnjaneyM You will get in both $\cos^2u+\sin^2u$ which simplifies to $1$.

Comment: so both the 2x2 matrices simplify to 1?

Comment: or in them theres a cos^2(u)+sin^2(u)?

Comment: @AnjaneyM Both look like the expression $\cos^2u+\sin^2u$ times some common factor of columns (not the same for both).

Answer (score 2):

There are some common factors that can be pulled out of the determinant: in the first column there's $\frac 15$, in the middle there's $\frac 15r(v+5)\sin(v)$, in the last there's $r$, and in the last *row* there's $\frac {33}{20}$.  Then expand along the last row.

Answer (score 2):

You can make life a bit easier by factoring out most of the nastiness:

$$\frac{33}{20}\left[\frac{v+5}{5}\right]^2 \left|\begin{matrix}
  \cos (u) \sin (v) & -r\sin(u) \sin( v) & r \cos(u)(\frac{\sin(v)}{v+5}+ \cos(v))\\
  \sin (u) \sin (v) & r\sin (v)\cos (v) & r \sin(u)(\frac{\sin(v)}{v+5}+ \cos(v)) \\
  \cos(v) & 0 & r\sin(v)
\end{matrix}\right|$$

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out

Comment: I do not see how you manage to factor $(v+5)/5$ out of the first column without affecting the last row.

Comment: I factored out from the rows, but you can factor out from either rows or columns.

Comment: Yeah i just noticed that. Factoring out only 33/20 doesn't make it much easier either

Comment: How did you factor out (v+5)/5 from the third row?

Comment: @AnjaneyM Remember, it's a **determinant**.

Comment: @John OK, I see.